# Image scale within image block issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, scale

Greeting,s using isotope plugin I've created fluid responsive grid for the page and would like to add some scale effect for the images within its size. The issue is that on 2 column media query in grows both in heigh and width, and in 3 column only in heigh, can you suggest what can be added to the code to stop it growing in size and worked kinda like a zoom effect.

**[Codepen.io link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gamwvd)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid"> 

                <div class="grid">

                  <div class="item">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                      <img src="img/7.jpg" alt="">
                      <p id="social_indicator">Facebook, 1 day ago</p>


                </div><!-- Grid --> 
        </div> <!-- Container fluid -->
    </div>  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>   <!-- /#wrapper -->
```

**CSS**

```
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 10s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 10s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 10s ease;
  -ms-transition:     all 10s ease;
  transition:         all 10s ease;
}

.item img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

}
```

P.S: I've loaded css style sheet inside codepen, [here is the link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyZGrY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some javascript to lock down the width and height of the images once they've loaded.

```
$(function(){
  $('.item-inner').each(function(){
    var img = $(this).find('img');
    $(this).css({height:img.height(), width:img.width()});
  })
})
```

Hide overflow on the .items

```
.item-inner {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Fashion your markup so the .items have an inner wrapper to contain the images.

Now your images will scale within the .item, but the .item won't grow.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYvpwd

Comment: Thank you bingo, that works perfect! Hope that will help others, too. :)